# How do I automatically split CSS-emulated table cells into multiple rows?

Tags: html, css, position, tablelayout

I am using the `display: table` and `display: table-cell` properties to evenly spread some divs across a parent. However, they all appear on the same row, so if there's too many, it cramps it up, like this:

[image]

I have set a `min-width` to the children but it is ignored. Is there a way to make the children automatically split into multiple lines if they go over a certain height? I won't always be able to determine the number of children, so I'd prefer to have just one parent div.

**HTML**

```
        <div class="panel-body select-body">
            <div class="board">
                <input type="checkbox"><span class="select-label">/a/</span></input>
            </div>
            <div class="board">
                <input type="checkbox"><span class="select-label">/a/</span></input>
            </div>
            <div class="board">
                <input type="checkbox"><span class="select-label">/a/</span></input>
            </div>
            <div class="board">
                <input type="checkbox"><span class="select-label">/a/</span></input>
            </div>
            <div class="board">
                <input type="checkbox"><span class="select-label">/a/</span></input>
            </div>
            <div class="board">
                <input type="checkbox"><span class="select-label">/a/</span></input>
            </div>
            <div class="board">
                <input type="checkbox"><span class="select-label">/a/</span></input>
            </div>
            <div class="board">
                <input type="checkbox"><span class="select-label">/a/</span></input>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.select-body {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.board {
    border: 1px solid blue; /* temporary */
    width: 15%;
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    display: table-cell;
}

.board > input[type="checkbox"] {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.select-label {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
```

Comment: The proper technique is to use float:left, that way they auto-wrap to the next line.

Comment: @Diodeus But then the width of the parent isn't fully covered. The children need to split equally and fill the whole width.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a way to split it into rows; the table cell solution is specifically for creating a single row.

What you're really looking for is flex-box. Have a look here for examples : http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/